# TikZ: numbering circle with overlapping square

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to number circle nodes using TikZ, so that this number is inside a small square that overlaps with the circle at the top (or bottom, or left, or right). I managed to do this separately drawing first the square and then the circle so that they overlap the way I want. However, given that I need to draw a lot of these, I was wondering if there is a way of doing it in a better way, so that I can create the circle with its square together without having to figure out their relative positions with respect to each other. Maybe making the square part of the circle decoration? Any ideas?

Here is what I have in mind:

[image]

And here is the sample code that reproduces it:

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    C/.style = {circle, draw, fill=white, minimum size=#1, inner sep=0mm},
    S/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=white, minimum size=#1, inner sep=0mm},
                   ]
\node[S=1cm, text depth = 0.5 cm,anchor=north] (a) at (0,0) {1};  % square
\node[C=4cm, below = -0.5cm of a] {label};                        % circle

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are many options, here is one based on pictures

---

(I had a bit of fun to make it quite configurable, and make it work around the circle and to configure the distance etc, EDIT: I added more configuration options as well to allow the text to be turned):

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,matrix}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  C/.style = {circle, draw, fill=white, minimum size=#1, inner sep=0mm},
  apply style/.code={\pgfkeysalso{#1}},
  apply style in macro/.style={apply style/.expand once={#1}},
  my decorator pic/.pic={
    \node[anchor=\myAnchor,rotate=-\myRotationAngleText,apply style in macro=\myExtraStyleText,](labelNode){\myText};
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
      \node[
        rotate fit={\myAngle},
        fit=(labelNode)(\myCurrentNode.center),
        rectangle,
        fill=\myColor,
        minimum size=\myMinimumSize,
        inner sep=0mm,
        apply style in macro=\myExtraStyle,
      ]
      {};
    \end{scope}
  },
  add deco/.style={
    append after command={
      \pgfextra{%
        \edef\myCurrentNode{\tikzlastnode}%
        \def\myAnchor{\myAngle+180}%
        \pgfkeysalso{
        set text/.store in=\myText,
        set color/.store in=\myColor,
        set color=pink!50!white,
        set position angle/.store in=\myAngle,
        set position angle=90,
        set minimum size/.store in=\myMinimumSize,
        set minimum size=8mm,
        set distance/.store in=\myDistance,
        set distance=0mm,
        set extra style/.store in=\myExtraStyle,
        set extra style=,
        set extra style text/.store in=\myExtraStyleText,
        set extra style text=,
        set text depth/.store in=\myTextDepth,
        rotate text angle/.store in=\myRotationAngleText,
        rotate text angle=0,
        rotate text bottom/.style={
          rotate text angle=\myAngle-90,
          /utils/exec={\def\myAnchor{90}},
        },
        rotate text top/.style={
          rotate text angle=\myAngle+90,
          /utils/exec={\def\myAnchor{-90}},
        },
        set text depth=2mm,
        #1,
      }}
    {($(\myCurrentNode.\myAngle)+(\myAngle:\myDistance)$) pic{my decorator pic}}
    }
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[C=4cm,
    add deco={set text=foo, set extra style={fill=red}},
    add deco={set text=foo, set position angle=-90, set extra style={fill=red}},
    add deco={set text=foo, set position angle=-90+25, rotate text bottom, set extra style={fill=red}, set extra style text={white}},
    add deco={set text=foo, set position angle=-90-25, rotate text top, set extra style={fill=yellow}, set extra style text={orange}},
    add deco={set text=foo, set position angle=90+25, rotate text top, set extra style={fill=green}, set extra style text={white}},
    add deco={set text=foo, set position angle=90-25, rotate text bottom, set extra style={fill=orange}, set extra style text={white}},
  ] (expl1) {Top label};
\node[C=4cm, add deco={set text=bar, set position angle=-90}, below=of expl1] (expl2) {Bottom label};
\node[C=4cm, add deco={set text=croco, set distance=10mm, set position angle=-90}, below=of expl2] (expl3) {Bottom label};
\node[C=2cm, add deco={set text=baz, set position angle=0}, below right=of expl1] {Right label};
\node[C=2cm, add deco={set text=bar, set position angle=180+45}, below left=of expl1] {Left label};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Added some more options

Comment: By the way, TikZ comes with a key `style` that does exactly the same as your `apply style` key. So, `style/.expand once=\myExtraStyle(Text)` should work as well.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel ohhh, such a good news, I've been dreaming for it a few times, thanks, will try it!